# How can I add entity framework migrations to different project than project with context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In project MyProject.DAL I have databasecontext. I would like to add entity framework migrations to project MyProject.Migrations so I write in console:

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName MyProject.Migrations -StartUpProjectName MyProject.DAL
```

But I have error:

**No context type was found in the assembly 'MyProject.Migrations'.**

why?

Answer (score 0):

So I know this has been a long time since this question has been asked, however, I have run into a similar situation and managed to figure it out.

For reference, have a look at [this link](http://wiki.ggtech.co.za/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-different-projects/).

It comes down to this type of syntax:

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName <Project Name> -ContextTypeName <Context Type Name including Namespace>
Update-Database -ProjectName <Project Name> -configuration <Namespace>.Migrations.Configuration -TargetMigration $InitialDatabase
Add-Migration -ProjectName <Project Name> -configuration <Namespace>.Migrations.Configuration Init -Force
Update-Database -ProjectName  <Project Name> -configuration <Namespace>.Migrations.Configuration
```

I hope this helps someone